# Why does the Torah sometimes use riddles, metaphor and misleading words instead of direct explanation?

Tags: commentaries, agada-stories-legends

If the Torah's lessons are critical for all to know, and written by Hashem, why is it sometimes so obtuse?

Let's focus this question on 2 places: the 3 sefarim of King Shlomo Shir HaShirim, Kohellet and Mishlei, and Aggada. Feel free to give a general answer.

It's pretty much impossible to learn almost *anything* from much of these without a commentary. On top of that, the commentaries often give very different lessons to draw from them.

If this passage in Shir HaShirim is reference to the *chet ha'egel*, why doesn't it just say *chet ha'egel*, why does it instead use some obscure metaphor? Why is Mishlei full of what are effectively riddles, which need to be solved, when it would be so much easier to have simply given the solution directly? Why is much Aggada so *strange*, with the direct meaning often *very misleading*, requiring a very clever commentary to explain it? E.g. Rabbah "shechting" R' Zeira, but the word "shecht" can mean "to elevate", and the underlying story is that he elevated him to a plane of depth of Torah that was above his level. etc.

This is not a *kasha*, I fully expect an amazing answer - I've heard many already but would like to broaden my knowledge.

Comment: See introduction of Rav Yaakov Loberbaum of Lisa to his introduction on Shir Hashirim, and see intro of Etz Yosef to his peirush on Ein Yaakov.

Comment: For the question on Meggilot of Shlomo see Gra on Mishlei 24:30 who says, "all the secrets of Torah are concealed in Aggadah (his reference is more to Meggilot Shlomo I think)." For the question on Aggadah see Rambam to intro to Mishnah, intro to Moreh Nevuchim, Moreh Nevuchim 1:70, Rav Chaim Friedlander in Siftei Chaim Emunah U'Bitachon Volume 2 page 385-390 and see more on page 371-465

Comment: 3 megillos of Shlomo HaMelech? He authored Shir HaShirim and Koheles? What was the third one you are referencing @RabbiKaii?

Comment: I just read more you are including Mishlei as a "megillah"?

Comment: @Dov sorry for the confusion, I've seen the term used like that before but I admit it is confusing